# Use CameraXConfig with CameraController

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camerax

I use the CameraController class to keep the code as simple as possible. (https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/view/CameraController). However, I have noticed that the PreviewView loads a bit slowly.

After some searching I found the possibility to set the configuration to speed up the camera initialization. (https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/CameraXConfig.Builder#setAvailableCamerasLimiter(androidx.camera.core.CameraSelector) and https://developer.android.google.cn/reference/androidx/camera/core/CameraXConfig)

But I don't understand how I can use the CameraController to set the settings. Does anyone know a way?

```
mExecutorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

mCameraController = new LifecycleCameraController(requireContext());
checkFailedFuture(mCameraController.getInitializationFuture());
runSafely(() -> mCameraController.bindToLifecycle(getViewLifecycleOwner()));
mCameraController.setImageCaptureMode(ImageCapture.CAPTURE_MODE_MINIMIZE_LATENCY);
mCameraController.setImageCaptureIoExecutor(mExecutorService);
```

I would like to include that: (My class already implements the CameraXConfig.Provider interface)

```
 @NonNull
  @Override
  public CameraXConfig getCameraXConfig() {
    return CameraXConfig.Builder.fromConfig(Camera2Config.defaultConfig())
        .setAvailableCamerasLimiter(CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA)
        .setCameraExecutor(mExecutorService)
        .build();
  }
```